# How do I get functionality of Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng() in .net 7?

Tags: vb.net

I have this function

```
Public Function compute64bitHash(ByVal someString As String) As Int64
    'Dim md5 = New Security.Cryptography.MD5
    Dim md5 = New Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng()
    Dim hashmd5 = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString))
    Dim hashmd5long = System.BitConverter.ToInt64(hashmd5, 0)
    Return hashmd5long
End Function
```

And for all practical purpose I don't want to change it.

It basically compute hash that I can compare latter.

After upgrading from framework 4.8 to .net 7 that error cause

The code works fine in framework 4.8

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30002 Type 'Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng' is not defined. nicehash2

I just want to rewrite the code. How do I?
Adding Imports System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 on to

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.MD5
```

on top of the file doesn't help either.

What should I import or reference to get that to work?

I look for the web and see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5cng?view=netframework-4.8.1

But that's for .netframework

What would be a good replacement for net 7

Comment: [CngAlgorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngalgorithm?view=net-7.0) ? As for _And for all practical purpose I don't want to change it._ then don't _upgrade._

Comment: Recommendations for tools are probably a little outside the scop of this form.  There is a Software recomendations stack maybe better suited.  That said as per @dr.null, why upgrade if you don't want to change?  You might also be able to get away with referenceing you .net framework project from .net7

Comment: Not really. I am just upgrading my code from framework to .net and for now I just want the code to run. That is well within the scope of stackoverflow I think.

Comment: Why upgrade if I don't want to change? Because it's a code that's rarely used. I will update that latter. Sure if someone would recommend a change, I'll consider it. I will change latter.